# Confused about the "NEW" keyword in SQL functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I'm relatively new to SQL/PostgreSQL and we just started working with triggers and functions/procedures.

These are the two relevant tables

```
CREATE TABLE Planes (
    regnr TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    capacity INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE AvailableFlights (
    date TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    price INT NOT NULL,
    nbrOfFreeSeats INT NOT NULL,
    flight TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES Flights(code),
    plane TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES Planes(regnr)
);
```

Where the table "Flights" contains some more info about arrivals etc. Anyways, so now I have the function like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_plane() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    size_difference INTEGER;
BEGIN
    size_difference := (SELECT capacity FROM Planes WHERE regnr = new.plane) - (SELECT capacity FROM Planes WHERE regnr = old.plane);

    IF(NEW.numberOfFreeSeats + size_difference < 0) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Plane too small';
    ELSE NEW.numberOfFreeSeats := NEW.numberOfFreeSeats + size_difference;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

And a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdatePlane BEFORE UPDATE ON AvailableFlights
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.plane <> OLD.plane)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_plane();
```

And so my question is this: How can I simply write NEW.nbrOfFreeSeats without SELECT with FROM and WHERE condition? And how does it know which row to change accordingly? Because the trigger will only be triggered when I write something like "UPDATE table SET plane = 'newVal' WHERE plane = 'oldVal', so in my opinion I'm never stating which nbrSeats I want to alter. Or is it implied from which plane I'm changing to? (To clarify: It is working properly and I'm just curious as to why).

I hope I'm making any sense, and this is my first post on stackoverflow so I hope I didn't make too many errors posting this (any feedback will be welcome though, kinda posted this in a haste):) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

As the [documentation states](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> NEW
>
> Data type RECORD; variable holding the new database row for
> INSERT/UPDATE operations in row-level triggers.

and also

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE [...] Returning a row value different from the original value of NEW alters the row that will be inserted or updated.

The example "Example 39-3. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Procedure" in that page might help too.

Comment: Oh I think I get it.. but in a previous example we also did a function, and then when we wanted to assign a value to something we declared at the top, we had to write ticket_price := (SELECT price ... WHERE flight = NEW.flight). Why couldn't we just write ticket_price := price?

Comment: @Yuna not sure about that. Did you try NEW.price in that case? Maybe you could post some code about this other situation or create a new question?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I solved it, thanks again!